# Why do implicitly unwrapped optionals need to unwrapped again in conditionals?

Tags: swift

Say for example I have class like so and instead of making fields that I will assign to in the `init` method I just want to have implicitly unwrapped optionals.

```
class foo {
  willBeSomeBool: Bool!
  willBeSomeString: String!
}
```

I understand the reason for doing this is so that when I declare them they will have an initial value of `nil` and thus I don't need an `init` as all the class's fields have initial values. All I need to do is make sure I assign something to them before I try and access them otherwise I will get a fatal error.

So say we've assigned values to the fields and now we are in some method, **what I'm asking is: why we need to forcefully unwrap the bool when we use it inside a conditional?** I can access other implicitly unwrapped optionals and even the bool without doing so outside of a conditional.

```
func bar() {
  if willBeSomeBool! {
    ...
  }
}

func buzz() {
  print(willBeSomeString)
}
```

My best guess for this is because we can still check for nil on the implicitly unwrapped variable so in the context of a conditional it is treated as if it was just a normal optional, but like I said its my best *guess*, and maybe I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why we need to forcefully unwrap the bool when we use it inside a conditional

It's a historical issue. Once upon a time, in the early days of Swift, an Optional could be used as a condition as a way of asking whether it was `nil`. There is thus a residual worry that you *might* think that `if willBeSomeBool` is a `nil` test. Therefore you have to either test explicitly for `nil` or unwrap so that we have a true Bool, thus proving that you know what you're doing — and preventing you from misinterpreting your own results.

Look at it this way. You can't say `if willBeSomeString`. You can only say something more explicit, either `if willBeSomeString == nil` or `if willBeSomeString == "howdy"`. So it is simplest to make `willBeSomeBool` obey that same pattern.

Comment: It's sort of in line with the Swift rule of trying not to surprise the programmer with secret meanings. They don't always obey that rule as well as they might, but you can see that they are trying; that's why `var` parameters and the increment/decrement operator and C-style for loops are going away.